# Build not starting automatically when merge code develop branch to master

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, github-actions

Hello we are github repository in this we have two repository one is MYtest(salesfoce code) another one is Script-deploy(python scripts and yaml scripts) when any merge the code in My test from devlop branch to master branch my azure ci pipeline not triggering automatically. should i change the code in i did connection already github to azure devops, i create service conections incoming webhook request-- gspconnection_new. can you when any code merges develop branch to source branch why pipeline is not trigeering automatically? please suggest me, in varibale section i am stroing variiable is it correct way or not.

```
trigger: none

resources:
    webhooks:
    - webhook: gspconnection_new          ### Webhook alias
      connection: gspconnection_new
      filters:
        - path: pull_request.merged  
          value: true
        - path: pull_request.base.ref  
          value: "master"


    repositories:
    - repository: Mytest  
      type: githubenterprise
      name: projectname/Mytest
      ref: develop
      endpoint: myrepo1

      extends:
      template: keyfiles.yml

variables:
    - name: devops_dir
      value: "/home/vsts/work/1/scripts-deploy"  
    - name: global_dir
      value: "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Mytest"
    #- group: varhashicorp
```

steps need to github to azure devops when merging the code pipeline run automatically.

Comment: Any idea why azure pipeline trigger automatically CI

Comment: You should set proper trigger - trigger: none prevents this from running.

Answer (score 0):

You have `trigger:none`. Please change it to

```
trigger:
- master
```